# CardView - mysterious gaps emerge when scrolling upwards

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I finally managed to get the card view to look just like I want it.
I use a `GridLayoutManager` with two columns to display cards with a thumbnail. Everything nice and working so far.

Anyway, once I scroll up, everything blows up. Large gaps (the size of a card itself) emerge between each row, now I every second row will be an empty one. I do not understand how that would possibly happen. I don't have any problem while scrolling down, but even one inch back up and everything is in pieces (so to speak).

Maybe some can see what is wrong with the layout.

actvivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/series_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSeriesTitle"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private List<Stuff> stuff;
private Callback callback;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    stuff = Collections.emptyList();
}

public MyAdapter(List<Stuff> stuff) {
    this.stuff = stuff;
}

public void setStuff(List<Stuff> stuff) {
    this.stuff = stuff;
}

public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public Stuff stuff;
    public View contentLayout;
    public ImageView thumbnailImageView;
    public TextView titleTextView;
    public TextView ratingTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        contentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_content);
        thumbnailImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ratingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    }
}

public interface Callback {
    void onItemClick(Series series);
}

@Override
public SeriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.series_card, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolderviewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    viewHolder.contentLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onItemClick(viewHolder.series);
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolderholder, int position) {
    Stuff stuff = this.stuff.get(position);

    holder.stuff = stuff;

    holder.titleTextView.setText(stuff.getName())
    holder.ratingTextView.setText(stuff.getStatus());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(stuff.getSomeImageURL())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.thumbnailImageView);
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stuff.size();
}
```

Comment: Post code also with the `getView` method of your adapter.

Comment: @x-code There is no such method, added the whole adapter.

Answer (score 0):

card.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Changing the layout_height to **wrap_content** fixed the problem.